# Why do we declare Private variables in Java?

Tags: java, variables, private-members

I'm confused because all I keep hearing is that private variables in Java are supposed to protect the code or the variable. But if anybody has access to the code, then it makes no difference if it is private, they can still change it. So how is it considered protected when anybody who has access to the code can change it?

Comment: See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables. Basically making some `private` is simply saying that this variable should be retrieved and acted upon as an interface and not directly. It protects the structure of how that item is used. Of course you can force change it in source code you have, likewise I someone could also completely delete code as well. It's a mute point once someone purposely messes up code.

Comment: So it is an etiquette thing?

Comment: Making something `private` means that you can't access it outside of that class, it has functional impact. What I mean is that you can make that point with *anything*. It's like saying: *"Why have constants if someone could make just make it into a normal variable"*? Someone modifying source code does not effect the importance of something. Along with that there are plenty of API's and libraries which you cannot modify the source code of

Comment: This is a concept of [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)), where access is restricted to internal state and is otherwise managed through methods (getters and setters), it ensures that the object can maintain a valid known state

Comment: Also if you were to provide your code as a jar library, then the user of the library will **not** have the code and will have to play by your rules

Comment: @FidoDido This is much more than just etiquette. See the second paragraph in my updated answer.

Comment: `private` is designed to protect ***you*** from ***yourself*** i.e. to help prevent you from making mistakes, if used well. In general, `private` helps to keep you from accessing a variable willy-nilly, so that when you go back later and you want to change or remove that variable, you don't have to fix a zillion places where you used it.

Comment: ``private`` is not meant to protect against malicious programmers, but is there to protect against certain types of bugs.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When programmers talk about accessing a variable, they mean accessing its **value** when the program runs. Protecting the code from changes is another matter entirely and requires human processes rather than syntax of a programming language. Making a variable private "protects" its value when the code runs. At this level, we are not concerned with protecting it from other programmers changing the code itself. The point of so-called "data hiding" is to keep internal data hidden from other classes which use the class. Those other classes should only access behavior by calling methods on the class, not by changing values of variables directly.

General programming principles such as "data hiding" are followed to help us as programmers write correct code. If any class can change a variable's value, then it is difficult to ensure that the value is valid. Say for example, you have a variable which counts the number of widgets a factory manufactures. By making the variable a private data member, you can more easily ensure that the value is never negative. On the other hand, if the variable is public, another class could change it to a negative value which can cause other parts of the code to crash.

Comment: Good Explanation! :)

Comment: But why other classes will do it, if we are creating other classes right?

Comment: @VishalSharma Other classes will do what?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Other classes can create an object of that class having the private variable. and call its setter. If it doesn't create a new obect, it could still call setter of the same object.  So Anothe class can still change it to a negative value causing other parts of the code to crash. What am I missing?

Comment: @veritas It sounds like you are asking a different question that is only loosely related to this one. Please click the "Ask a Question" button at the top of the page so you can fully ask your question with more details and relevant code examples. Feel free to add a link to this question from your own question, if it makes sense to do so in the context of your question.

Comment: @veritas The short answer is that you should use `unsigned` when a variable is not allowed to be negative. This has nothing to do with `private`.

Comment: To many of you it might seem like this explanation makes sense, but I find it wrong for multiple reasons.

First, if other classes should access public methods...and use those to change one class' variables, then there's really no protection from the bad practice of "modifying data from all over the place" anyway.

Second, java DOES NOT protect data "when the program runs". It protects data "when the programmer writes code". At run-time, one can (afaik) edit private fields, or even add methods without a big problem.

Comment: Conclusion (because I was limited to 500 characters):

Programs need to be structured carefully. Private fields don't really help EXCEPT when using libraries. For library maintainers, it makes a lot of sense to NOT expose certain fields, as they might plan to change/remove those fields in later versions.

In practice, Python for instance, has no problem with exposing private variables. In later versions of the library, those variables can be replaced with automatic getter/setter logic (called "properties" in Python).

I haven't found a use-case for private variables in 9 years of xp :|

Comment: @vlad-ardelean I originally read the question as "how is a variable `private foo;` 'protected' when I have access to the code and can change it to `public foo;`?" My answer is an attempt to clarify that `private` doesn't stop someone from editing the code but gives protections at compile time and run time for how the value of that variable is allowed to be set. Granted some of my wording is clunky and probably inaccurate. I'm open to suggestions to improve it

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the wording is fine, I was addressing the issue from a completely different perspective. I have not found good explanations of why visibility modifiers exist, or rather the explanations were an unclear mixture of "not sure" with "it's good for the programmer". Was just trying to shed some light on that aspect of the java ecosystem/community/culture.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean the reason is detailed below by Ari Singh. With private variables we can make class variables read only by creating getters without setters.

Comment: @mister_cool_beans I think vlad is perfectly aware of what `private` means.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice how is that relevant ? Vlad has stated "I have not found good explanations of why visibility modifiers exist". I provided  explanation...

Comment: @mister_cool_beans Did you read the previous comments that lead up to that? I read it as "I have not found good resources online which explain this. Here's my take." In the context of this discussion, vlad clearly understands what `private` means.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You are confused, I am not talking about what private means. I am providing a reason as to why private exists, i.e. a functional use for private, a reason as to why they exist in response to Vlad stating "I have not found good explanations of why visibility modifiers exist"

Comment: @mister_cool_beans So you are explaining something to vlad that he already explained in his own comment earlier.

Comment: @mister_cool_beans You're right. I thought that vlad's original comments were showing "a different point of view" as he claims. But as I go back to read vlad's comments, he seems confused about access modifiers more than I thought.

Comment: @mister_cool_beans The original question is 4 years old and vlad's comments are a year old. Hopefully he's already cleared up any confusion since then.

Answer (score 10):

Variables are private to protect the state of your objects - in object-oriented programming terms, this is called [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

Here's a very simple example.  Imagine that we have a Person class, and a Person has an age that is calculated based on the year in which they were born.

```
class Person {

    private int yearOfBirth;
    private int age;

    public Person(int yearOfBirth) {
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;

        this.age = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - yearOfBirth;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

In another class somewhere, we have this... and if age was public, we could really mess up the state of our object by changing it without updating the year of birth.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person bob = new Person(2000);

    System.out.println("Bob's age: " + bob.getAge());

    bob.age = 100;  //This would be BAD!
}
```

By encapsulating the age variable, it's safe from unexpected changes and our class can manage its own state.  Anyone who uses our class doesn't have to care about calculating a person's age, because that's encapsulated within our class.

Comment: in this particular example I get what you mean but imagine that apart from the getter which you have determined by the getAge() method, we may have also setter as well, so the mess might happen again, no?

Comment: If you explicitly add a setter to the class, then yes, it becomes possibly to mess up the internal state of the class again.  However, I would argue that that breaks encapsulation then - age is internal to the class and is controlled by logic in the class.  The only setter to add in this example should be something to change the birth year, in which case age is recalculated - so age is encapsulated.  Adding a setter for it results in the same outcome as just making it public, so in my opinion, both of those would be poor design.

Answer (score 7):

> why are variables private in java

To achieve encapsulation and this ***can't be accessible outside the class***. This doesn't mean programmer can't change the source code.

Answer (score 4):

"Private" variable means "controlled" access not "no" access. e.g. I can make the variable read-only by having only a getter method and no setter method. The owning class decides the access to to be provided to the variable - via methods it exposes to the public.

Also I can validate the value before storing it and reject values that are not allowed. I can also log the changes to the value.

It can also synchronize multiple variables so that it can be all in a consistent state e.g. doing debits and credits simultaneously.

And no - other people cannot change my code e.g if I provide my code as a compiled "jar" file. Or if they change it, and they break it - they own it (i.e. be responsible for the consequences their code change does).

An analogy from a real life would be room mates sharing expenses thru a shared wallet. If the wallet is public - anyone can take money from the wallet - no accountability. But let's say one of the room mates (owning class) owns the wallet (private variable) - and provides a "getter" (you ask for money and I will give you from the shared wallet) to access the wallet - there is more accountability. No more anyone taking the money from the wallet will nilly. The keeper of the wallet can then log all access to it - in case of bugs (disputes) - to troubleshoot the problem. Similarly "addToWallet" method (room mates contributing to the wallet) can be used to add money to the wallet - again with more accountability as opposed to wallet lying in the open with any of the room mates adding 
 / removing money from it willy nilly.

Answer (score 2):

Public = accesible with other Class

Private =  not accesible with other Class

> So if you have a private variable, it will not be accesible with other Class

Answer (score 2):

**Data Hiding/Encapsulation:**

Data hiding is not same as Abstraction. Not to confuse one with the other.

> Abstraction is hiding the code implementation from other Object/user
>   whereas Data hiding is achieved by Encapsulation via POJO classes.
>
> Data hiding has to do with the instance variables which decides the
>   state of the Object. Hiding its content using the setter() and
>   Getter() methods is Data Hiding/ Encapsulation.

You may wonder, how a getter() method is hiding the data whereas it just returns the data we requested but there is an untold story about the getter/setter methods.

**Example:**  **Refer the getName() method from the below code**

```
public class Person  {


    private  int age;
    private  String name;



    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
       // can restrict the code without displaying data to user
         if(condition)//restricted user check
            return null;//returning null because the user is not supposed to view the data

        return name;
    }

}
```

This can only be possible if the access modifier is private because if they are public or other we can directly access them through the object. If it is private, only then you have the ability to restrict your code.